# Is it possible in Grafana using a source data table with a JSON field, to get an attribute from that field?

Tags: grafana

We configure **Grafana** to use a table input data source, it works very well with the fields already defined (like time, status, values, etc.).

But now a new `field` has been added to the table that is a serialized JSON object, returned from a process we can not modify.

We need to use a value (timestamp) that is a property of this serialized object in that table string `field`.

One serialized `field` value example is this:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-02-23T18:25:44.012Z","status":"fail","errors":[{"timestamp":"2020-02-23T18:25:43.511Z","message":"invalid key: key is shorter than minimum 16 bytes"},{"timestamp":"2020-02-23T18:25:43.851Z","message":"unauthorized: authorization not possible"}]}
```

The pretty print is:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-02-23T18:25:44.012Z",
  "status": "fail",
  "errors": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-02-23T18:25:43.511Z",
      "message": "invalid key: key is shorter than minimum 16 bytes"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-02-23T18:25:43.851Z",
      "message": "unauthorized: authorization not possible"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to use a value like: `field.timestamp` or `field.errors[0].timestamp` ?

Is there a Plugin that allows it ?, or is not possible at all ?

Comment: The most important info is missing: used datasource. What is that "table input data source"? MySQL, PostreSQL, Elasticsearch, ............?

Comment: Is PostgreSQL with native support JSON data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PostgreSQL JSON column select](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-query-a-json-column-in-postgresql/) in your Grafana query, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  field->'timestamp',
...
```